# jQuery list check .each only works on last item

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of addresses which I want to check against if the same address for an input value also exists in this list. The problem is with my `each` function it only seems to check the last `li` and doesn't check the rest.

I've seen similar questions but nothing worked with my function.

Here is the HTML:

```html
<ul>
  <li><span class="savedLocDropTxt2">LA Office</span><br>
    <span class="savedDropAdd2">125 Pico Blvd, Santa Monica, CA 90404, USA</span>
  </li>
  <li><span class="savedLocDropTxt2">NY Office</span><br>
  <span class="savedDropAdd2">1001 West 31st Street, NY, New York 10001, USA</span>
  </li>
    <li><span class="savedLocDropTxt2">NY Loft</span><br>
  <span class="savedDropAdd2">1453 West 21st Street, NY, New York 10001, USA</span>
  </li>
</ul>

<h4>Start Address</h4>
<input class="startAddInput2" style="width: 250px;" name="StartAddress1" type="text" value="1453 West 21st Street, NY, New York 10001, USA">
<br>
<span class="savedLocTxt2"></span>
```

Here is the JS:

```javascript
$('.savedDropAdd2').each(function(){
    if($(this).text() == $(".startAddInput2").val()) {
        $('.savedLocTxt2').text('exists');
    }
  else {
    $('.savedLocTxt2').text("doesn't exist");
  }
});
```

and [here is the jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/omws2v5d/)

It only shows the address exists in the list if you put the last address as the text field value attribute, where it should say exists for any address value which also exists in the list.

Comment: Note you are setting the same element in your loop `$('.savedLocTxt2').text()` so only the last set value is going to be shown. `.text()` does not append/concatenate values on its own. Did you mean to use concatenation or similar method to show all values that were set? ie `element.text( oldText+newText ) `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong in using `text()` method here. The problem is how to break out of the `each` loop after you have successfully found a match.

if you don't do this and a match is found as any other element apart from the last element, the code will always return `"doesn't exit"`. This is because the last element will always be tested for even if a match is found among the other other elements.

To break out of the `each` loop immediately after finding a match, simply return `false` and the problem is solved.

```js
$('.savedDropAdd2').each(function() {
  if ($(this).text() === $('.startAddInput2').val()) {
    $('.savedLocTxt2').text('exists');
    return false;
  } else {
    $('.savedLocTxt2').text("doesn't exist");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <span class="savedLocDropTxt2">NY Loft</span><br>
    <span class="savedDropAdd2">1453 West 21st Street, NY, New York 10001, USA</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="savedLocDropTxt2">LA Office</span><br>
    <span class="savedDropAdd2">125 Pico Blvd, Santa Monica, CA 90404, USA</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="savedLocDropTxt2">NY Office</span><br>
    <span class="savedDropAdd2">1001 West 31st Street, NY, New York 10001, USA</span>
  </li>
</ul>

<h4>Start Address</h4>
<input class="startAddInput2" style="width: 250px;" name="StartAddress1" type="text" value="1453 West 21st Street, NY, New York 10001, USA"><br>
<span class="savedLocTxt2"></span>
```

Comment: Thanks, the return false was what I was missing to accomplish what I wanted!

Answer (score 0):

Patrick's comment is exactly right - what do you expect to know about what addresses were found if your flag is changing per iteration? you need an array to know how EACH address was compared

```
var comparison = [];
$('.savedDropAdd2').each(function(){
    if($(this).text() == $(".startAddInput2").val()) {
        comparison.push(true);
    }
    else {
        comparison.push(false);
    }
});
```

Each index of the `comparison` array will have if that item was found or not

You can also add an object into the array with more details

```
comparison.push({idOfElementBeingCompared: valueOfComparison});
```

concatenation can be messy. You usually want to stick with data structures so you can later use the data in your app?

Answer (score 0):

The loop is done as intended but the issue is that you're replacing the `span.savedLocTxt2` text in each loop iteration.

To get it to work and shows if the `input`'s value (the typed address by the user) exists or not for every address (the `span.savedLocTxt2`) then you'll need to append the result rather than directly assigning it through `text` method.

> in the next example, the `html` method is used instead of `text` to allow line breaks (`br` tags).

```js
const spanAdresses = $('.savedDropAdd2'),
  input = $(".startAddInput2"),
  savedLocTxt2 = $(".savedLocTxt2");
  
let  html = ''; /** holds the generated HTML for a better performance **/

spanAdresses.each(function() {
  html += savedLocTxt2.html() + $(this).text() == input.val() ? "exists" : "doesn't exist" + "<br>";
});

/** assign the generated HTML **/
savedLocTxt2.html(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="adresses">
  <li><span class="savedLocDropTxt2">LA Office</span><br>
    <span class="savedDropAdd2">125 Pico Blvd, Santa Monica, CA 90404, USA</span>
  </li>
  <li><span class="savedLocDropTxt2">NY Office</span><br>
    <span class="savedDropAdd2">1001 West 31st Street, NY, New York 10001, USA</span>
  </li>
  <li><span class="savedLocDropTxt2">NY Loft</span><br>
    <span class="savedDropAdd2">1453 West 21st Street, NY, New York 10001, USA</span>
  </li>
</ul>

<h4>Start Address</h4>
<input class="startAddInput2" style="width: 250px;" name="StartAddress1" type="text" value="1453 West 21st Street, NY, New York 10001, USA">
<br>
<span class="savedLocTxt2"></span>
```

Answer (score -1):

Whether something exists is false by default and true if you find a match. Your code should reflect this.

```
$('.savedLocTxt2').text('doesnt exist');
$('.savedDropAdd2').each(function(){
    if($(this).text() == $(".startAddInput2").val()) {
        $('.savedLocTxt2').text('exists');
    }
});
```